# How to add timezone drop down in wordpress with contact form 7 plugin?

Tags: html, wordpress, drop-down-menu, wordpress-theming, contact-form-7

I am creating a website and it contains query form which includes **timezone dropdown** .
How can we add time zone drop down using Contact form 7 ??

```
Attached is output I want.
```

Thanks in advance!!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [wp_timezone_choice](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_timezone_choice/) function available within WordPress. This function returns values in `<option>` form so you can use something of below sort:

```
<select>
    <?php echo wp_timezone_choice( '' ); ?>
</select>
```

**Please note** that I have passed empty string so that user can select an option. If you want any timezone to be preselected then you can pass the same timezone instead of empty string.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will need a timezone database.  There are several which you can google for or donwload one from [here](https://timezonedb.com/download).

Next import your data into WordPress, if you have a CSV file you can use the plugin [Really Simple CSV Importer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-csv-importer/) to import the timezones as a taxonomy for example.

The other option is to import the data as a separate table in your DB, it all depends on how you want to manage the data. If you want to be able to differentiate timezones between different continents/countries/regions then best to store them as a taxonomy and create parent terms for each region you want to differentiate.

Next to display them in your form, use the dynamic dropdown field available with the [Smart grid-layout extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) plugin.

The dynamic dropdown allows you build a select field using either a list of terms from an existing dropdown (see this video [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9he4Tca5o8&t=260s) on how to use it) or using a custom filter and programmatically building the list (see this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9he4Tca5o8&t=1198s)) using your database custom table if that's the way you imported your timezone data.

Last but not least, the dynamic dropdown also allows you to transform your select field into a [select2](https://select2.github.io/) field which is handy for large lists as it allows your users to search for a particular timezone.